# Export nested groups a contact is a memberOf

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm using Exchange 2010 and Powershell.

I'm looking to export all 'nested' distribution groups that a exchange contact is a part of.

For example, if a contact is a memberOf two DG, A and B. And group A is also a memberOf Group C. I'd like a list the show all three groups.

```
      Group C      
    ----|-----------|
     Group A     Group B
             |
          Contact
```

Here is my very noob attempt at this. I guess it needs to be done recursively?

```
$contact = get-contact email@domain.com.au

$members = Get-ADObject -Identity $contact.Guid -Properties 'MemberOf' 

foreach ($group in $members.MemberOf) {  

    foreach ($_ in $group.memberof ){ 

    get-distributiongroup $_ 

    }
}
```

Must be able to do this for a 'contact', not a user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need Exchange to get distribution groups.
Here's my example to retrieve names of groups assuming your contact is AD user with mail property filled:

```
function Get-GroupsRec
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
$Identity
)
BEGIN {}
PROCESS{
    if($Identity -eq $null){return}
    Write-Output $Identity | select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
    $Identity | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | ?{$_.GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} | Get-GroupsRec}
END{}
}
Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq 'email@domain.com.au'} | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | ?{$_.GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"} | Get-GroupsRec
```

But as long as you can retrieve AD user, this solution is valid.

UPDATE:
Version basing on `Get-ADObject` only. (Same structure, only different selectors. Left ObjectClass in filter for readability):

```
function Get-GroupsRec
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
$Identity
)
BEGIN {}
PROCESS{
    if($Identity -eq $null){return}
    Write-Output $Identity | select -ExpandProperty Name
    $Identity | select -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Get-ADObject -Properties GroupType,MemberOf |?{$_.GroupType -gt 0 -and $_.ObjectClass -eq 'group'} | Get-GroupsRec }
END{}
}
Get-ADObject -Filter {mail -eq 'email@domain.com.au'} -Properties MemberOf | select -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Get-ADObject -Properties GroupType,MemberOf |?{$_.GroupType -gt 0 -and $_.ObjectClass -eq 'group'} | Get-GroupsRec
```

If you want restrict group type to a specific type, you may modify GroupType in code to any value with `-band` operator. The enumerator values are available at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772263(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hey Deptor,
Thanks for the solution. The contacts do have the mail property filled. I'm still very new to PS and so I'm having trouble following your code. I tested your script and didn't receive any errors, however I don't have an output as well.

Comment: @jez none at all? First: are you sure you don't assign to a variable the last line of the code? Then output will not show. Secondly, I suggest to run last line by each part to find the cause (by each '|'). The function is only responsible for recursion.

Comment: @jez fixed the code. Fixed a small mistake in function and changed the selected property to the one that is sure to be non-empty

Comment: thanks mate. Will have a look. Meanwhile, here's my process and output: https://img42.com/GZktz

Comment: @jez From the process, it looks to me like the user could not be found in the domain. Is the machine, where you run the script inside the same domain? Try `Get-ADUser login_of_the_user -Properties mail`

Comment: okay so I believe Get-ADuser is the problem. The contact is not a user, hence I replaced it to use 'Get-ADObject - Filter ..... ' But then get an issue with 'Get-AdPrincipleGroupMembership  : cannot find an obj with identity.'

Comment: @jez updated answer with version for Get-ADObject only, since you say it is working fine for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: that works!! thanks so much! how do I close the case and promote your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You indeed need recursion for this. I quickly put something together which should recusively resvolves membership. Hope this helps!

```
Function Get-Groups {
    Param(
        [string]$Identity
    )

    $members = Get-ADObject -Identity $Identity -Properties "MemberOf"
    $members.MemberOf | % {
        if($(Get-ADObject $_ -Properties "GroupType").grouptype -gt 0) {
            Write-Host $_
        }
        Get-Nestedmember $_ "->"
    }
}

Function Get-Nestedmember {
    Param(
        [String]$Identity,
        [string]$Depth
    )
    $members = (Get-ADobject -Identity $Identity -Properties "MemberOf").memberof
    $count = $members | measure
    if($count -ne 0) {
        $members | % {
        if($(Get-ADObject $_ -Properties "GroupType").grouptype -gt 0) {
            Write-host "$Depth $_"
        }    
            Get-Nestedmember $_ "-$Depth"
        }
    }
}
Get-Groups -Identity '<Your Identity goes here>'
```

It gets a MemberOf relationships and does that again for the resulting set. If MemberOf returns 0 that means there are no more MemberOf relationships so we stop.

Comment: Your function will return also security groups. Question mentions only distribution.

Comment: @Deptor Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks guys, but the issue is this search will be for a particular contact/email address not a user. For example, e.g. John Doh - john@domain.com.au 

Using 'Get-ADObject -Identity' with a contact gives me issues with ' cannot find object with identity...'